# How to call two POM.xml in sequence from Jenkins?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have two POMS. Let's say POM-1 and POM-2

POM-1 is used for getting the source from SVN validating, packaging and then putting into the nexus repository. Then this executed from Jenkins UI . The input parameters 
are passed from UI.

POM-2 is used for getting the package from nexus and do the deployment process. Again this is also executed from the Jenkins UI and the i/p parameter is passed from UI.

Both the POM's have their own SDLC phases. POM-1 has to be executed first and then POM-2 has to be executed.

The user has to run two Jenkins Jobs to do the deployment. I want to merge these POM's and make it as single jenkins job.

I tried various approaches to merge these two but it got failed. Need your help/guidance to merge the POM's and run single Jenkins Job.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can configure the second job to be ran automatically after first one.
   Thus use will just press the button for the first job and the second one will be built automatically.
2. You can create a parent POM that lists your existing projects as modules. And you refer only the parent project to Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Could you pls explain in detail, how to do this ? I want to merge both the POM's and run only one job.

Comment: What I meant is keep the two jobs, but in the Jenkins configuration of the second job check the "Build after project... " option and select the first one.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But everytime to deploy a new application we have to create two Jenkins jobs. I want to make this happen in single job. In other words for every new application will create only one job in which all the tasks to be completed. Any idea ? Appreciate your help

Comment: ok. If I refer my parent POM in Jenkins then how do I pass input params to my child projects. Currently both the projects/poms are getting the input from Jenkins UI.

Comment: The input parameter are passed to the child projects. They can either be provided on the command line in Jenkins UI or as properties in the parent pom.